# Visualizing High Dimension Space Using Tensorflow Embedding Projector: No dashboards are active for the current data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, embedding

I'm trying to visualize my data in high dimension space using the Tensorflow embedding projector tool and I'm fed up with this error. It's been so many hours that I have been trying all other options but nothing worked. My event files are located in this directory 'C:\Users\sethuri\Documents\VectorSpaceModels\NEW\logs\emb' and I've tried the below commands in my notebook to make the embedding project but nothing has been successful so far. Any help is appreciated

```
%tensorboard --logdir=./
%tensorboard --logdir /logs/emb/
%tensorboard --logdir ./
%tensorboard --logdir="./"
%tensorboard --logdir='./'
%tensorboard --logdir=C:\Users\sethuri\Documents\VectorSpaceModels\NEW\logs\emb
%tensorboard --logdir='C:\Users\sethuri\Documents\VectorSpaceModels\NEW\logs\emb'
%tensorboard --logdir=C:\Users\sethuri\Documents\VectorSpaceModels\NEW\logs\emb\
```

and every time I launched tensorboard I made sure that I deleted the previous tensorboard process using this code and tried with different command

```
! powershell "echo 'checking for existing tensorboard processes'"
! powershell "ps | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq 'tensorboard'}"
! powershell "ps | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq 'tensorboard'}| %{kill $_}"
! powershell "echo 'cleaning tensorboard temp dir'"
! powershell "rm $env:TEMP\.tensorboard-info\*"
! powershell "ps | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq 'tensorboard'}"
```

I'm on Windows 10
Python - 3.8.9
Tensorflow -2.3.0

**Error**

[Error Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjLRk.png)

Comment: please post the error message as text rather than as picture, it might help other user who encountered same error

Comment: Please click on the Error image screenshot

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_projector_plugin) to define and use `Tensorboard` for Embedding Projector.